# HTML capture enter key and tab key

Tags: javascript, html

I want to prevent the enter key from submitting the form, I want it to act as a TAB key to just jump to the next field in the form or the next element.

Is this possible in HTML/JS?

if not possible to make the enter button act as a tab, is there a way to prevent the submission of the form and make only the form be submitted using the buttons on the HTML??

***EDIT:***

I have received a solution to this problem when I was asking for another problem!

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596558/form-submission) you can find the solution.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but why confuse your users by changing the default behaviors? It's better to validate the form (`onsubmit`) and ask the user to correct their answers if they are missing a field, or have bad input.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I want to prevent form submission on enter key, I want it to be done with the buttons on the form only.

Comment: I am able to read; what you're suggesting is a bad idea. "why?" you're bound to ask. You probably haven't thought about accessibility. Users who are blind rely on certain interactions (namely: tab and enter) to submit forms. If you nix those keycodes, you're ruining their experience. **don't do it**.

Answer (score 2):

For accessibility/usability reasons, you really shouldn't prevent the `Enter` key from submitting the form (assuming the browser was going to do that anyway; IIRC, some older browsers didn't).

Assuming that you want to do this because the submit button has a `click` handler you'd like to happen for *every* form submission, you should instead move that code into a separate function and invoke it from a the form's `submit` event.

In jQuery, it would look something like:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
        if (!isValid()) {
            e.preventDefault();  // Could also be `return false;` but I prefer preventDefault.
        }
});
```

See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

FYI, if you're trying to do some validation, you should check out the [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Comment: The form has no default action, so the form shouldn`t submit unless a button is pressed. And I don`t think disabled people will use this from (at least for now) ... IF in any time in the future my client decides to make it available to disabled people we can use something like voice to direct them to the fields.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to solve this using some jQuery - although I don't know how to imitate a keypress.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13)
  {
    //Code to imitate keypress of Tab key
  }
});
```

Edit: Made a quick jsFiddle to "imitate" tab presses, which would go to the next field like you mentioned. (This one works based on the Enter key being pressed in a field)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XkELX/)

Comment: I'm looking for alternatives - The previous suggestion had several positive reviews, thought it might.

Comment: +1 A down vote for something that was a valid answer, sourced from stackoverflow that was upvoted and for whatever reason didn't work is a little harsh.

Comment: A downvote for this isn't entirely unwarranted, since the `keyCode` property of `Event` objects is read-only in all browsers except IE. I haven't downvoted it though.

Comment: Don't change your answer with edits, either append or write a new answer.

Comment: Sorry - also accidentally clicked rollback thinking it would go back to it's previous state.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function tmpFn(val){
    if(event.keyCode=='13'){
    if (val<4)
        document.forms["yourform"].elements["box" + (val+1)].focus();
    else
        document.yourform.submit();
    return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
<body>
<form name="yourform" action="#">
<input type="text" name="box1" onkeypress="return tmpFn(1)"><br>
<input type="text" name="box2" onkeypress="return tmpFn(2)"><br>
<input type="text" name="box3" onkeypress="return tmpFn(3)"><br>
<input type="text" name="box4" onkeypress="return tmpFn(4)"><br>
<input type="submit" name="done" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: Refrain from using 'eval'.. Thanks Tim and Andy!

Comment: Please don't be evil.  Change your `eval` line to `document.yourform['box' + (val+1)].focus()`

Comment: Even better, change it to `document.forms["yourform"].elements["box" + (val+1)].focus();`

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, to prevent the enter button from submitting the form, don't use a submit button, rather use a `<input type="button" ... onclick="submitForm();">` to call javascript to submit the form.  I could be wrong, but I believe this should prevent pressing enter on any other element submitting the form.

Comment: this is a good idea, mklauber. I was looking for something like the ASP, and didn`t think about that at all ...

Comment: The return key doesn't click the submit button, it just submits the form using the specified `action` URL.  That means that even if you get rid of the submit button, the form will still submit when you press the return key.

Comment: @Andy E that's [not correct for HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#implicit-submission). If no submit button is defined, the enter key wont do anything. I believe that is the same behavior seen in HTML4, just made explicit in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: @zzzBov: it looks like we're both half-right :-) If there's a submit button, enter "clicks" the button.  If there's no button, the form submits itself. From that same section of the spec you linked to, *'If the form has no submit button, then the implicit submission mechanism must just submit the form element from the form element itself.'*