# form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this form:

```
<form id="basicTerms" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

and the function in the `onsubmit` is below:

```
function validateForm()
{
    return false;
}
```

I've done this to test the form, and when I click Enter or click on a button on the form that performs triggers the form submit action, the form submits and moves to the next page.

I also have these buttons in the form:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left"><button style="background-color:#FF80FF" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('basicTerms').action='helpFile1.php'; document.getElementById('basicTerms').submit()" tabindex="6">Go Back</button></td>
    <td align="center"><button style="background-color:#FFC080" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('basicTerms').action='helpFile2.php'; document.getElementById('basicTerms').submit()" tabindex="4">Lets Go To Step 2</button></td5>
    <td align="right"><button style="background-color:#00FF00" onclick="printThis()" tabindex="5">Print</button></td>
</tr>
```

I want to know why the forms submits even when I return a false in `onsubmit`.

I've tested the form on Google Chrome and FireFox, both gave the same result. Also, I'm testing on localhost WAMP: Apache2.2.11, PHP5.3.0.

Comment: Try adding `type="button"` to your button tags. Otherwise I believe they default to submit buttons.

Comment: @Cfreak: please post this comment as an answer so that I can choose it.

Comment: done. I thought it might work but I wasn't 100% sure :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `type="button"` to your button tags. Otherwise I believe they default to submit buttons.

(added as an answer since it worked as a solution)

Comment: You saved the day :D ... Since I have multiple buttons and each do a specific action, so the form shouldn`t work like that on Enter key, and by this solution, you solved me another problem. So another +1 (wish I could make it :D)

Answer (score 2):

A call of ***form*.submit()** doesn't trigger the submit-event, validateForm() will be ignored.

Comment: OK, but even if I hit the Enter button on any text field in the form it just submits!

Comment: depending on the browser(happens for example in FireFox & Opera) the use of [ENTER] can trigger a click on the first submit-button, form.submit() will be called and so on.

Comment: How can it solve the problem,  validateForm() will never be called with this solution?